# How to get all recylerview item views in activity?

Tags: java, android

i want to save all recycler view item views from the activity. after Changning modifications. but here only coming those those views are visible. but I want for all item views which not currently showing also

This is my adapter class

```
public class MultifitRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MultifitRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Bitmap> selectedBitmaps;
    Context context;

    String selectedFilterConfig;

    String selectedAdjustConfig;
    private float mScaleSize;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> backgroundImgList;
    int height;
    boolean isRatio;
    int ratioWidth;
    int ratioHeight;

    public MultifitRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Bitmap> selectedBitmaps, Context context, float mScaleSize, ArrayList<Bitmap> backgroundImgList) {
        this.selectedBitmaps = selectedBitmaps;
        this.context = context;
        this.mScaleSize = mScaleSize;
        this.backgroundImgList = backgroundImgList;
        this.selectedAdjustConfig = "";
        this.selectedFilterConfig = "";
        isRatio = false;
        this.height = 985;
    }

    public void setSelectedBitmaps(ArrayList<Bitmap> selectedBitmaps) {
        this.selectedBitmaps = selectedBitmaps;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setmScaleSize(float mScaleSize) {
        this.mScaleSize = mScaleSize;
    }

    public void setRatio(boolean isRatio) {
        this.isRatio = isRatio;
    }

    public void setRatioWidth(int ratioWidth) {
        this.ratioWidth = ratioWidth;
    }

    public int getRatioWidth() {
        return ratioWidth;
    }

    public void setRatioHeight(int ratioHeight) {
        this.ratioHeight = ratioHeight;
    }

    public int getRatioHeight() {
        return ratioHeight;
    }

    public void setBackgroundImgList(ArrayList<Bitmap> backgroundImgList) {
        this.backgroundImgList = backgroundImgList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MultifitRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.multifit_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.ivCover.setImageBitmap(this.selectedBitmaps.get(position));

                    holder.ivFrame.setImageBitmap(backgroundImgList.get(position));

            holder.ivCover.setScaleX(mScaleSize);
            holder.ivCover.setScaleY(mScaleSize);
        if (isRatio) {
            height = holder.cRatio.getHeight();
            holder.cWrapper.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ratioWidth, ratioHeight));
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.ivCover.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = ratioWidth;
            layoutParams.height = ratioHeight;
            holder.ivCover.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
            constraintSet.clone(holder.cRatio);
            constraintSet.connect(holder.cWrapper.getId(), 3, holder.cRatio.getId(), 3, 0);
            constraintSet.connect(holder.cWrapper.getId(), 1, holder.cRatio.getId(), 1, 0);
            constraintSet.connect(holder.cWrapper.getId(), 4, holder.cRatio.getId(), 4, 0);
            constraintSet.connect(holder.cWrapper.getId(), 2, holder.cRatio.getId(), 2, 0);
            constraintSet.applyTo(holder.cRatio);
        }

    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return selectedBitmaps.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public PhotoEditorView pvEditor;
        RectangularLayout rectangularLayout;
        public ImageView ivFrame, ivCover;
        public ConstraintLayout cRatio;
        public FrameLayout cWrapper;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            pvEditor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_editor_view);
            ivFrame = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivFrame);
            ivCover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivCover);
            cRatio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cRatio);
            cWrapper = itemView.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_wrapper);
            rectangularLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_wrapper_photo);
        }
    }
}
```

and then im taking view from adapter like this and saving them in gallery like this

```
    class SaveBitmap extends AsyncTask<Void, String, List<String>> {

        SaveBitmap() {

        }

        public void onPreExecute() {
            // customLoader.hide();
            //  customLoader.show();
        }

        public List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < multifitRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
                MultifitRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder = (MultifitRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder) multiFitRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                if (holder != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(holder.pvEditor.getWidth(), holder.pvEditor.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap1);
                    holder.pvEditor.draw(canvas);

                    try {
                        String filename = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
                        File file = SaveFileUtils.saveBitmapFileRemoveBg(MultifitActivity.this, bitmap1, filename, null);
                        if (file != null) {
                            filePaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return filePaths;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(List<String> filePaths) {
            // customLoader.hide();
            if (filePaths == null || filePaths.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.went_wrong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(MultifitActivity.this, MultiShareActivity.class);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("path", (ArrayList<String>) filePaths);
            startActivity(i);
            AdsManager.showAdmobInterstitialAd(MultifitActivity.this, "PhotoEditor");
        }

    }
```

here i want save all items from reyclcerview item views but it saving only two images which showing.